# makefile, compile list of sources stuck on first file

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile

I have a very extrange problem.

I'm working with makefile and Eclipse to compile a program for an AVR microcontroller. The basic idea is to create a project handled by a makefile, and everything works well if I only have one (1) source file, but if I add more than one source file, just the first file is compiled as many time as objects (.o files) I want to create.

I think is better with the example below:
This is a snipet of my makefile:

```
PROJ_DIR = /home/namontoy/workspace-AVR/exampleBitCloudMakefile
SDK_ROOT = /opt/cross/avr
LIST_PATH = $(CONFIG_NAME)/List
EXE_PATH = $(CONFIG_NAME)/Exe
OBJ_PATH = $(CONFIG_NAME)/Obj

# Create list of sources and list objects
SRCS := $(shell find . -type f -name '*.c')
OBJECTS :=  $(SRCS:.c=.o)

# Second for to create list of sources and objects
#SOURCES=$(wildcard $(SRCS)/*.c)
#OBJECTS_AUX=$(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCES))
#OBJECTS = $(subst $(PROJ_DIR),$(OBJ_PATH), $(OBJECTS_AUX))

directories: 
   @echo
   @echo $(MSG_MKDIR) $@
   @"mkdir" -p $(LIST_PATH)
   @"mkdir" -p $(EXE_PATH)
   @"mkdir" -p $(OBJ_PATH)

# Compile: create object files from C source files.
$(OBJECTS) : $(SRCS) directories
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_BUILDING) $<        # print message of begining build
    @echo srcs: $(SRCS)             # print list of sources
    @echo objects: $(OBJECTS)       # print list of objects
    @echo '$$< is "$<"'             # print file to be compiled
    @echo '$$@ is "$@"'             # print name of object file
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    @echo $(MSG_FINISH_BUILDING) $<    # print message of finished build
```

On the terminal, make prints:

```
Building file: dummyFile.c
srcs: ./dummyFile.c ./LearningInterrupt_Main.c
objects: ./dummyFile.o ./LearningInterrupt_Main.o
$< is "dummyFile.c"
$@ is "dummyFile.o"
avr-gcc -g           -c   -O1            -std=gnu99      -Wall           -mmcu=atmega328p        -fshort-enums           -funsigned-char             -funsigned-bitfields        -fpack-struct           -Wstrict-prototypes         -Wa,-adhlns=dummyFile.lst   -I/opt/cross/avr/avr/include -I/opt/cross/avr/lib/gcc/avr/4.8.3/include -I/opt/cross/avr/lib/gcc/avr/4.8.3/include-fixed -I/home/namontoy/workspace-AVR/exampleBitCloudMakefile/headers -I/home/namontoy/workspace-AVR/exampleBitCloudMakefile/ dummyFile.c -o dummyFile.o
Finished building: dummyFile.c

Building file: dummyFile.c
srcs: ./dummyFile.c ./LearningInterrupt_Main.c
objects: ./dummyFile.o ./LearningInterrupt_Main.o
$< is "dummyFile.c"
$@ is "LearningInterrupt_Main.o"
avr-gcc -g           -c   -O1            -std=gnu99      -Wall           -mmcu=atmega328p        -fshort-enums           -funsigned-char             -funsigned-bitfields        -fpack-struct           -Wstrict-prototypes         -Wa,-adhlns=dummyFile.lst   -I/opt/cross/avr/avr/include -I/opt/cross/avr/lib/gcc/avr/4.8.3/include -I/opt/cross/avr/lib/gcc/avr/4.8.3/include-fixed -I/home/namontoy/workspace-AVR/exampleBitCloudMakefile/headers -I/home/namontoy/workspace-AVR/exampleBitCloudMakefile/ dummyFile.c -o LearningInterrupt_Main.o
Finished building: dummyFile.c
```

So, as you can see, make read all sources files and objects, but when the second object file is going to be created, make didn't run over the list of sources, it stucks on the first source file.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

namontoy.

Comment: From the [makefile docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html): "$<  The name of the **first** prerequisite."

Comment: regarding this line: `SRCS := $(shell find . -type f -name '*.c')`  Do you have a statement, near the top of the makefile, that defines which shell to use?   Suggest using a line like: `SRCS := $(wildcard *.c)`

Comment: this line: `$(OBJECTS) : $(SRCS) directories` would be better written as: `%.o:%.c`   And only getting first file compiled over and over because of this line: `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@`,  Which would be just fine if using the suggested line

Comment: The use of the `echo ...` command in the posted makefile would be better replaced by: `<tab># ...` which amongst other things means the external command `echo` would not be invoked over and over.

Comment: strongly suggest you add a couple more parameters to your compile line.  Suggest: `-Wextra`   Note that mixing `-g` and `-O1` will give you problems when debugging the code.

Comment: A makefile produces a 'cascade' of events to be executed.  Therefore, the makefile should be written as a cascade of events.   Generally, this means the first 'target' is `all` and that target has dependencies of the  order of things to be done.  suggest: `.PHONY: all`  then `all: $(EXECNAME)`  then `$(EXECNAME): $(directories)  $(OBJECTS) followed by the linker recipe then `%.o:%.c $(HEADERS)` followed by the compile recipe.  It would be a good idea to generate the dependency files via recipe then change ``%.o:%.c $(HEADERS)` to ``%.o:%.c %.d` so not every file is re-compiled on a single chan

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
$(OBJECTS) : $(SRCS) directories
    ...
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

You make *every* object depend on *all* sources. And the automatic variable `$<` takes the first prerequisite, which will be the first source file in the list, no matter what you're trying to build.

Try a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
%.o : %.c directories
    @echo compiling $< to produce $@
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: Hi! Many thanks for all the answers and comments. I have made two changes sugested by @beta and @user3629249 and everything works but with one side effect. with `$(OBJECTS) : $(SRCS) directories` I wass trying to generate the objects files on a specific folder, but now, with  `%.o : %.c directories` the building process put the objects files on main folder, next to sources (.c) files. I also try `$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o : %.c`  and `$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o : $(PROJ_DIR)/%.c`, but doesn't work

Comment: @namontoy: I don't know why `$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o : %.c` isn't working (nor how it fails), but that's a separate question-- wich has been asked and answered several times on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by :

```
%.o: %.f90
    $(FC) $<  $(INC) $(LIB) $(FLAGS) -o $(addprefix $(BINDIR)/, $(notdir $@))
```